# How to use JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm reading Learning Rails 3.  In the section on JavaScript it says to rename your file from *.js.coffee to just *.js if you want to use JavaScript instead of CoffeeScript.  Well I did that and the JavaScript doesn't work.  When I converted the JavaScript to CoffeeScript (and renamed the source file back to *.js.coffee), everything works fine.

any ideas?
mike

Comment: That's what you get with Rails, "edgy" stuff.

Comment: it does work, perhaps you had an error in your JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is check the server output of files, to ensure it's loading the javascript file.

1. Restart the development server
2. Check the javascript include and the manifest file including it

Answer (score 0):

The application.js file should consist of all the javascript files you want to include, however if it has '// require_tree .' present then all the javascript present in the directory will be included.